# How to Make Bootable APFS Volume From Disk Image

Tags: macos, startup, dmg, apfs

I am currently using terminal to early and quickly add APFS volumes to my Mac's APFS container.

Once I make an empty APFS volume in the container, how can I copy a disk image to it and make it bootable? I have tried using `dd`, but there have been various issues that seem to keep this from working. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is under-constrained (hence unclear): what's the content of the disk image and what's the file system of the original source?

Comment: Thanks @klanomath. It's an Apple Diagnostics disk image that's currently formatted as macOS Extended.

Answer (score 2):

I would try `rsync`. Below is an example of the syntax. Here, I assume the `source` is the mounted disk image volume and the `destination` is the apfs volume.

```
rsync  -a  /Volumes/source/*  /Volumes/destination
```

Comment: Will this make the destination volume bootable? If I use `dd` to copy the image to an SD card, for example, the SD card becomes bootable and works as expected. Running this command just places the `System` folder on the volume. This volume is still not available at boot when holding the `option` key.

Comment: Probably not. But, you are unclear about what you are trying to do. Can I assume you are trying to take an image created from a bootable JHFS+ volume and restore to a APFS volume and still be bootable? If the answer is yes, then the result will not boot. A single JHFS+ volume can be bootable, while APFS requires multiple volumes to boot macOS.

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY solution to making a disk image of an APFS formatted drive that contains the operating system (macOS) can be found here:

[How can you create a valid/reliable disk image of APFS drives?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399974/how-can-you-create-a-valid-reliable-disk-image-of-apfs-drives)

Apple has either intentionally blocked this or have simply not gotten around to making a solution easily possible. BUT there IS a solution, as shown at the above thread.

Comment: Does this mean the questions are duplicates of each other? Is there something that differentiates the question you've linked to versus the question you've written this answer on?